# subprocess waiting until the end to continue

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

This snippet of code:

```
  reply = subprocess.Popen(Command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  data, error = reply.communicate()
  outputText.insert("end", data + "\n")
```

At the moment it runs the entire subprocess (looping over a bunch of lines) and only THEN will run the outputText bit.

What can I change to run outputText for each loop of the script and not when the subprocess has completed. I tried a .wait() on the end, but it errored with a "'int' object has no attribute 'communicate'" message.

Thanks,
Chris.

Edit: This is an example of one iteration of the output of command:

```
Ignoring profile '\\MachineName\C$\Users\UserName1' (reason: directory inclusion)
Ignoring profile '\\MachineName\C$\Users\UserName2' (reason: directory inclusion)

The following user profiles match the deletion criteria:

\\MachineName\C$\Users\UserName3
```

There could be many lines included in the output.

Comment: Do you mean you tried `reply = subprocess.Popen(...).wait()`? Instead, try `reply = subprocess.Popen(...)` as you have it now, then `reply.wait()` on its own line. (I don't know if `wait` is even useful in this circumstance, but this ought to at least fix your attribute error)

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. It got rid of the error, but you're right - was no help at all. lol.

Comment: So you want to print each line of output from `Command`, while `Command` is still executing, rather than only after it's finished?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling `communicate`, which will block until `Command` completes, you need to iterate over the `stdout` attribute of `reply` directly:

```
reply = subprocess.Popen(Command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in reply.stdout:
   outputText.insert("end", line +"\n")
```

This will insert each line of `stdout` from the subprocess into `outputText`, one at a time, until `Command` completes.

**Edit:**

Here's how to do what you're trying to do with the "loops" you're talking about. You would need to add the logic for `is_end_of_loop` yourself.

```
out = ""
for line in reply.stdout:
   out += line
   if is_end_of_loop(line):
       outputText.insert("end", out +"\n")
       out = ""
```

Comment: Thanks @dano. I've edited my original Q to include an example of the command output.

There could be multiple lines included in this. If I change my code to your example above, it runs the line to outputText for EVERY line in the command output. I need it to only run for each LOOP of command. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Does anyone else have any suggestions...?

Comment: @user3514446 It sounds like you still want to iterate over `reply.stdout` line by line like in the code above, but instead of calling `outText.insert` for each line, you need to append each line to a variable until you know you've got a completed loop. You would identify that by parsing each line and looking for whatever it is that identifies it as the last line of a loop. See my edit for a code sample.

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing this isn't going to work (at least, not in the way I'd like)...

As per the example I added to the original question, there could be 1 or 100 similar lines, just with a different user id on the end. The command doesn't have an 'end' as such..